# Rotating a 3 coordinate point

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

Im having trouble figuring out how to rotate the z axis 90 degrees. For a programming im making

example 
   new_x = y;  // For a 90 degree clockwise rotation, the new x is the original y,
    new_y = -x; // and the new y is -1 times the original x.
So what would Z be. If its not to clear please let me know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations

Answer (score 0):

A vector $(x,y,z)$ rotated about *z* 90° is $(-y,x,z)$